# Calculate average in SQL based on condition for end date and number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-partitioning

I want to calculate average value for records looking similarly like the ones in the table below (this is just an example, values does not matter):

[image]

I have query looking like this:

```
SELECT Id,
AVG(Value) OVER(partition by ID Order by [date] rows between 2 preceding and current row) as avg_value,
FROM [table]
WHERE Code = 'SLS' --- there are more codes usually
```

The conditions I want to add but cannot decide how to do so properly are:

1. Calculate average only when the maximum `Date` for each `Id` is `>=` from current year minus 1
2. Calculate average only when I have values for the number of years I specify which in this case is 3.

Both conditions must be met. In this case Id = 2 does not meet even one of the conditions.

Comment: The two conditions seem conflicting.  I don't understand the second one at all.

Comment: The second condition means that if i have met the firs one but only have data for 2 years back I don't want to make the calculation because I want average of 3 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution which seems to be working:

```
SELECT Id,
AVG(Value) OVER(partition by ID Order by [date] rows between 2 preceding and current row) as avg_value,
FROM (
      SELECT *, 
             Max([Date]) OVER(partition by Id, Code) as MaxDate, 
             COUNT(*) OVER(partition by Id, Code) as RecordsPerCode
      FROM [table]
      WHERE Code = 'SLS'
  ) a
  WHERE 1=1 
  AND YEAR(MaxDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))
  AND RecordsPerCode >= 3
```

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the first condition using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Id,
       AVG(CASE WHEN date > dateadd(year, -1, date) THEN Value END)
           OVER (partition by ID
                 order by [date] rows
                 between 2 preceding and current row
                ) as avg_value
FROM [table]
WHERE Code = 'SLS' --- there are more codes usually
```